# horizontal ruler does not appear in firefox

Tags: html, firefox

I have my wrapper divided in 3 columns with a simple grid (floating).

After each third column jQuery puts a horizontal ruler like this:

```
<div class="col-1-3">a</div>
<div class="col-1-3">a</div>
<div class="col-1-3">a</div>
<hr>
<div class="col-1-3">a</div>
<div class="col-1-3">a</div>
<div class="col-1-3">a</div>
<hr>
```

And so on...

This works in Internet Explorer and Chrome, but Firefox doesn't display these `<hr>` tags for some reason.

Example:

http://markefka.phinksta.de/leistung.php

Comment: Run your page through a validator. You have a stray div somewhere which is probably causing this.

Comment: If you use ctrl-u in Firefox, it will highlight that you have an extra `</div>` in there.

Comment: thanks Andrew. Very good to know, didn't even notice !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at it with the Inspector tool, the `<hr>` tags are displayed, they merely aren't positioned the way you expect them to be. Since the `<div>` elements are floating, to have `<hr>` display after them you need:

```
hr {
  clear: both;
}
```

Adding this seems to do what you expect.

For reference: [`clear` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear)

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are using the wrong syntax. Also in the comments to your question the suggestions are wrong.
Always rely on official documentation or very good sources.

The right syntax for hr is `<hr>` without closing tag.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zp83F/

Try the fiddle on Firefox.

**EDIT**

Also looking at your actual code, Like Wladimir Palant well said: adding a clear:both; can fix the issue.